# Removing closed questions, abuse of moderation(?)

Tags: discussion, deletion, deleted-questions

I recently wondered about a loss in reputation (-28), and I was confused, because I did not get a notification. 
Since the reputation loss was a little bit higher, I assumed that some user was deleted. I got curious when I did not get a mention about it in my reputation history.

After a while I noticed the 'show removed posts' button, what solved the mystery for me. Before the post was removed, I noticed that the answers in the thread were downvoted.

So it turns out that someone deleted a question that was closed, but how ever had more then one answer with a noteable amount of upvotes.
Also the question was a little bit older, so I wonder about the reason to delete an answered question after a year or so.

A while ago, I got a message from a moderator, because I deleted some of my own answers, which I found were not adding anything to the site, or simply got no attention anyways. I was told to eventually see everything posted as a part of the site (more or less...). So it seems really odd to me, that a question gets simply deleted from the website.

For me it seems like an abuse of moderation tools.

[image]

Comment: Do you have a link to the deleted post?

Comment: @Jack No, because the post was deleted. :)

Comment: Using [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24(x%5E2-4x%2B4)%5E2%3D0%24&p=1) one can find the [deleted post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2962166/9464). I believe 10K+ is needed to view it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The question you refer to were closed and deleted by regular users (with exactly one person voting on both actions, which is entirely allowed).

There is no abuse, this is how community-moderation takes place.

Self-deletions are different. They are not community moderated, quite the opposite. They are user-moderated. Sometimes it's someone trying to cover their tracks of doing something wrong, or someone rage-quitting and removing their contributions. And in those cases we usually intervene. Sometimes it's clear that this is just someone trying to clean up their profile, in which case we may sometime send a message and sometimes not.

The point here is that there is a lot of things on this site which need to be deleted. This includes a lot of questions, and there are different opinion as to whether or not good answers are worth enough to preserve bad questions. Sometimes they are, sometimes they are not.

So some dedicated community members try to close and remove content they see unfit. You can dispute this by requesting questions to be undeleted and reopened, but you'd need to make your case, and the truth is that often times there is no actual case to make. These deletions are there to remind you, and everyone else, to pick and choose which answers you spend your time on.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, did not notice that there are 'community deletes'.

Comment: @Cornman If you want to learn a bit more about voting to delete (="community deletions"), some basics are mentioned in the page [about the corresponding privilege](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools). And there is very detailed FAQ posts - probably explaining much more details that a typical user needs to now - on [meta.se]: [How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean? What are the criteria for deletion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)